# Matching columns with similar strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-match

I am trying to match the columns based off the first 8 characters and the last 2 characters so i would then be able to run a vlookup on it:

[image: Data set]

The issue is the middle of the cell is always different in the first column is all 10 in the middle, the second 25 and so on. I tried collecting the first 8 and last two characters by a left and right and then tried an approx vlookup but it wasn't working for me just showing an error for me.

My attempt

```
=LEFT(C2,FIND("/",C2)+3) & "    " & RIGHT(C2,FIND("/",C2)-3)
```

Gives me this:

```
20.5/010    ES
```

Trying to run off Col B in the photo

Desired result:

[image: Desired Result]

Here is the Error I am receiving:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have three different type of data e.g.; 20.5/010/010/, 20.5/010/025/ & 20.5/010/022/ and you will delete your column B (which is empty in your input data) you will have column A, B and C populated (Makes sense?)

Your output data clearly shows you have a list of 010 values in column 10 and you want to know if there is a match for the other two values with the same country code. But I'll make that column D in this example. So:

- Have column D populated like your output column 10.
- Add this formula to column E and drag down:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B;MATCH("20.5/010/025/"&RIGHT(D1;2);B:B;0);1);"")
  ```
- Add this formula to column F and drag down:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(C:C;MATCH("20.5/010/022/"&RIGHT(D1;2);C:C;0);1);"")
  ```

My output:
[image]

Comment: I have populated column D exactly as Column A which i think is what you asked me to do, I am getting an error when trying to paste the formula in Column E  and it highlights the INDEX(B:C   "C" area of the formula. Any idea why this may be occurring

Comment: To me this work fine, I found a minor mistake in the second formula. But using them gives me the output that I will update the answer with...

Comment: I am copying exactly what you have and still no luck with the formula for me, i dont understand why the formula wont work you have exactly the type of answer i am looking for but cant get it to work.

Comment: Its still giving me the same error, about the array from B:C, Its identical to yours so no clue why its occurring, ill show the error in the original post so you can see

Comment: Edited once more. This also works with me still.... columns changed e.g. B:B and C:C and reference column always 1. Pls post your formula if still no luck. Ill try your version in my sheet.

Comment: still no luck and i tried exactly what you had, is it possible to post the spreadsheet on here or no, i am new to stackoverflow ?

Comment: Give me your exact formula fist pls

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B;MATCH("20.5/010/025/"&RIGHT(D1;2);B:B;0);1);"")

Comment: Okey, easy fix. Your excel works with "," instead of ";". Try it again with: =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH("20.5/010/025/"&RIGHT(D1,2),B:B,0),1),"")

Comment: Just back from my lunch break and YES it works, Thank you so much you don't know how long this was taken me to do. I appreciate your help more than you can understand. Thank you